How to use a custom fork of Drake with a Python venv/pip install?
What is the easiest way to use a custom fork of Drake in a Python venv?
As an open-source project, many people add minor features to Drake which never make it into master and so it would be nice to be able to pip install these forks in isolated python environments to make switching between them easier.

Pre-reqs

If you are building with Ubuntu make sure you have docker installed.
Make sure you add yourself to the docker group (call sudo usermod -aG docker <username>). You may need to logout/reboot for this to work.

Instructions
**Warning: ** This method of installation will NOT enable Gurobi and may not allow you to build with SNOPT (see instructions (here).
In this example, I will assume that your project is located as ~/my_project and that you have successfully cloned the Drake repository to ~/drake

Step into the drake folder using cd ~/drake
Run the mandatory install prereqs script by running sudo ./setup/ubuntu/install_prereqs.sh (see instructions (here).
Build the wheels using bazel run //tools/wheel:builder -- 0.0.0 --python=310. Feel free to replace 0.0.0 with a different version number. Be sure to change the --python=310 tag to your python version. This will build the wheel in the drake folder
Step into your project folder using cd ~/my_project
If you have not yet created your venv, make one by calling python venv ./.venv
Activate your venv by calling source ./.venv/bin/activate. (If you skip this step you will install drake to your global python which is not what you want)
Call pip install ~/drake/<path_to_wheel>.

Pitfalls
Here are some pitfalls that people have encountered in the past.
Docker errors

ERROR: invalid empty ssh agent socket: make sure SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set. You will see this if you are not part of the docker group. The wheel building script needs to be able to create a docker container without calling sudo

Python Import Errors

AttributeError: module 'drake' has no attribute...,  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", or ImportError: initialization failed
This error frequently happens when pip is confused about the drake library. It is very important that the venv only sees one version of Drake. Missteps that have caused this in the past include

If your file system is setup as ~/my_project/drake (i.e. drake is inside your project) then the ~/my_project/drake/__init__.py file will break your venv.
If your PYTHONPATH has a spurious copy of Drake (e.g. you installed Drake from source globally) then you may see this error.



